# REACT - Image gallery

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs

I'm retrieving images from the database in REACT and have created a holder for an image with thumbnails at the bottom.

I would like to know how I can make the interface behave like eCom sites, whereupon clicking the thumbnail, its respective image is loaded in the bigger area.

Below is the REACT code.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ImageList from "../ImageList";

const ProductDetails = props => {
  const images = require.context(
    "../../../strapui/app/public/uploads",
    true,
    /\.jpg$/
  );
  const keys = images.keys();
  const svgsArray = keys.map(key => images(key));

return(

<div className="desContainer ">
    <div className="desimgContainer ">
        <ImageList
        styles="heroImage"
        imagePath={props.selectedItem[0].image[0]}
        svgsArray={svgsArray}
        />
    </div>
    <div className="thumbs">
        <ImageList
        styles="thumbnail"
        imagePath={props.selectedItem[0].image[0]}
        svgsArray={svgsArray}
        />
    </div>
    <div className="thumbs">
        <ImageList
          styles="thumbnail"
          imagePath={props.selectedItem[0].image[1]}
          svgsArray={svgsArray}
        />
    </div>
    <div className="thumbs">
        <ImageList
          styles="thumbnail"
          imagePath={props.selectedItem[0].image[2]}
          svgsArray={svgsArray}
        />
    </div>
</div>
);
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

The images are pulled from the database using the following code

```
import React from "react";

const ImageList = props => {
  if (
   props.imagePath === undefined ||
   props.imagePath === null ||
   props.imagePath.length === 0
  )
  return null;
const path = props.svgsArray.find(
str => str.indexOf(props.imagePath.hash) > 1
);


return <img src={path} alt={props.imagePath.hash} className={props.styles} />;
};

export default ImageList;
```

I was wondering if I could use a switch case to show the image when a thumbnail is clicked?

will it work? if it will, can you pls direct me how?

Answer (score 0):

Use onClick event and attach it with some function which should do some code magic.

for e.g:

```
largeSizeImage () {
    /* some code logic */
    }

return (

<div className="thumbs" onClick={largeSizeImage()}>
        <ImageList
          styles="thumbnail"
          imagePath={props.selectedItem[0].image[1]}
          svgsArray={svgsArray}
        />
    </div>

)
```

Comment: I had tried what you had suggested. It throws me an error saying the function is not defined. Any suggestion on how to debug it?

Comment: @IshaqSheikMohamed sorry, answer updated.  You can add console.log('function fired!')  inside your largeImageSize function.

Comment: Its still the same

Comment: it's not working... in case you haven't noticed, the first set of codes is a functional component.